# Authentication using PG 10 scram-sha-256 password encryption

Tags: qgis, postgresql, authentication

My PostgreSQL 10 database is configured to encrypt passwords using the `scram-sha-256` algorithm. I can't establish a connection from QGIS 2.18, as it fails with the following error:

> authentication method 10 not supported

[image]

What can I do to connect to the database using the `scram-sha-256` password encryption?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The PostgreSQL client that comes with QGIS 2.18 was build against PG 9.2.4, and it therefore doesn't contain the required code to use `scram-sha-256` password encryption.

You can copy the updated libraries from a PostgreSQL 10 installation to make use of the new features.

1. rename `C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\libpq.dll`  to `libpq.dll.backup`
2. From the folder `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin\`, copy the files `libpq.dll`, `libintl-8.dll` and `libiconv-2.dll`
3. paste the 3 files to `C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\`

Comment: I also had to include the libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll and libssl-1_1-x64.dll in the second step (with postgresql 13)

Answer (score 1):

*(Just in case anyone has this issue)*

I had a similar problem creating a connection from QGIS 2.18 to PostgreSQL 13. Using the answer from [@JGH](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/84870/jgh) plus the comment added by [@Bourboul](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/103161/bourboul). I was able to solve the problem.

1. Rename C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\libpq.dll to libpq.dll.backup
2. From the folder C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin, copy the files libpq.dll, libintl-8.dll, libiconv-2.dll, libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll and libssl-1_1-x64.dll
3. Paste the 5 files to C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\

The initial solution fron [@JGH](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/84870/jgh) did not fix, but after adding the the files mentioned by [@Bourboul](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/103161/bourboul) it worked for me.