# Authentication method 10 not supported (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, postgis, connection, pgadmin-3

I have a problem when I am trying to connect the database that I have in pgadmin with my QGIS project. I am trying to create a New PostGIS connection like in the following picture:

[image]

But I am always getting the following when I am trying to connect with my credentials to the database.

[image]

Do you know what should I do in order to solve it? I have checked that solution but it doesn't work for me ([Authentication using PG 10 scram-sha-256 password encryption](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/284280/authentication-using-pg-10-scram-sha-256-password-encryption))

PS: I am using QGIS3.6 and pgAdmin 4 v6.

Comment: Click the Store button? for username/password

Comment: @Mapperz I have done it already but this doesn't change the error!

Answer (score -3):

this worked for me: [QGIS failure in PostGIS connection: "ident authentication failed for user"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/332227/qgis-failure-in-postgis-connection-ident-authentication-failed-for-user)

> The local connection (to 127.0.0.1) worked if I use trust in
> /etc/postgresql/11/main/pg_hba.conf:
>
> host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
> host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust

Comment: "Trust" actually means anyone can connect without password